# Select Records between undetermined date range from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, for example Table1 and Tabl2 and I'm using Oracle SQL

**Table1**

```
|  ID  |    DATE   |
|------|-----------|
|   1  | 1/20/2021 |
|   1  | 5/2/2021  |
|   2  | 6/8/2021  |
```

**Table2**

```
|  ID  |  RF_DATE |  AMT  |
|------|----------|-------|
|  1   | 1/25/2021|  15   |
|  1   | 2/20/2021|  25   |
|  1   | 5/21/2021|  50   |
|  2   | 6/10/2021|  20   |
```

Starting with Table1 I want to match the results from table2 where the date from table2 is in between the dates from table1 if there are multiple date rows in table1.  In other words the dates from table2 should always be after the dates from table1 without unnecessary duplicating the ID for every matching ID and record that occurred after the DATE.

Expected output:

```
|  ID |  Date    |  RF_DATE  | AMT  |
|-----|----------|-----------|------
|  1  | 1/20/2021|  1/25/2021|  15  |
|  1  | 1/20/2021|  2/20/2021|  25  |
|  1  | 5/2/2021 |  5/21/2021|  50  |
|  2  | 6/8/2021 |  6/10/2021|  20  |
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "unnecessary duplicating the ID"

Comment: Is this your database design? If so, you _really_ should rename your PK columns to be more self-documenting than just "ID".

Comment: Looks like you just need `lead(dt, 1, date'9999-12-31') over(partition by id order by dt ) as next_date` and then use it in join as `rf_date between dt and next_dt`

Comment: You say "between" and then "should always be after" in the next sentence. Please, decide, what you actually need. And show your current attempt. Look like you need `exists`